# iTextSharp System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, itext

I have an issue with trying to create a large PDF file. Basically I have a list of byte arrays, each containing a PDF in a form of a byte array.  I wanted to merge the byte arrays into a single PDF.  This works great for smaller files (under 2000 pages), but when I tried creating a 12,00 page file it bombed).  Originally I was using MemoryStream but after some research, a common solution was to use a FileStream instead.  So I tried a file stream approach, however get similar results.  The List contains 3,800 records, each containing 4 pages.  MemoryStream bombs after around 570.  FileStream after about 680 records.  The current file size after the code crashed was 60MB.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code I have, and the code crashes on "copy.AddPage(curPg);" directive, inside the "for(" loop.

```
    private byte[] MergePDFs(List<byte[]> PDFs)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        byte[] completePDF;
        Guid uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string tempFileName = Server.MapPath("~/" + uniqueId.ToString() + ".pdf");

        //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using(FileStream ms = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (byte[] PDF in PDFs)
            {
                i++;
                // Create a reader
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PDF);

                // Cycle through all the pages
                for (int currentPageNumber = 1; currentPageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++currentPageNumber)
                {
                    // Read a page
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage curPg = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber);

                    // Add the page over to the rest of them
                    copy.AddPage(curPg);
                }

                // Close the reader
                reader.Close();
            }

            // Close the document
            doc.Close();

            // Close the copier
            copy.Close();

            // Convert the memorystream to a byte array
            //completePDF = ms.ToArray();
        }

        //return completePDF;
        return GetPDFsByteArray(tempFileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of notes:

1. `PdfCopy` implements `iDisposable`, so you should try and see if a `using` helps.
2. `PdfCopy.FreeReader()` will help.

Anyway, not sure if you're using MVC or WebForms, but here's a simple working [HTTP handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) tested with a *15 page 125KB* test file that runs on my workstation:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MergeFiles" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.IO; 
using iTextSharp.text; 
using iTextSharp.text.pdf; 

public class MergeFiles : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        List<byte[]> pdfs = new List<byte[]>();
        var pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/app_data/test.pdf"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; ++i) pdfs.Add(pdf);

        var Response = context.Response;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=MergeLotsOfPdfs.pdf"
        );
        Response.BinaryWrite(MergeLotsOfPdfs(pdfs));
    }

    byte[] MergeLotsOfPdfs(List<byte[]> pdfs)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Document document = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfs.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(
                            new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfs[i]), null))
                        {
                            copy.AddDocument(reader);
                            copy.FreeReader(reader);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Tried to make the output file similar to what you described in the question, but YMMV, depending on how large the individual PDFs you're dealing with are in size. Here's the test output from my run:

[image]

Comment: I am using an older version of iTextSharp which will not allow me to use "using" for Document, PdfCopy, and PdfReader, but man, if you got 60,000 pages with nearly 1/2 a gigabyte of data to work for you, then your code is what I want people to look at first, not mine.  Giving you checkmark and up-vote.  Thank you kuujinbo!

Comment: @Lukas - sorry to hear you can't use this solution, but **thank you** for the nice comment. :) Before this, never tried to generate anything larger than ~2000 or so pages, so your question is interesting and gets an up-vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of messing around, I realized that there just was no way around it.  However, I did manage to find a work-around.  Instead of returning byte array, I return a temp file path, which I then transmit and delete there after.

```
    private string MergeLotsOfPDFs(List<byte[]> PDFs)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        Guid uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string tempFileName = Server.MapPath("~/__" + uniqueId.ToString() + ".pdf");

        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (byte[] PDF in PDFs)
            {
                i++;
                // Create a reader
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(PDF), null);

                // Cycle through all the pages
                for (int currentPageNumber = 1; currentPageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++currentPageNumber)
                {
                    // Read a page
                    PdfImportedPage curPg = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber);

                    // Add the page over to the rest of them
                    copy.AddPage(curPg);

                    // This is a lie, it still costs money, hue hue hue :)~
                    copy.FreeReader(reader);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            // Close the document
            doc.Close();

            // Close the document
            copy.Close();
        }

        // Return temp file path
        return tempFileName;
    }
```

And here is how I send that data to the client.

```
        // Send the merged PDF file to the user.
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=1094C.pdf;");
        response.WriteFile(tempFileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
        DeleteFile(tempFileName); // Call right after flush but before close
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
```

Lastly, here is a fancy DeleteFile method

```
    private void DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Could not delete the file, wait and try again
                try
                {
                    System.GC.Collect();
                    System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Could not delete the file still
                }
            }
        }
    }
```